# What is the quantum phenomenon called where a very cool liquid glides over a container to a lesser potential energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I've seen a demonstration of this. Now I can't find anything similar anywhere.

Comment: [Film flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#Film_flow) in a superfluid?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you mean.

I write this summary of the article, just to learn more about the fascinating phenomenon, of which I had baically no  knowledge of previously.  Thank you to @knzhou for saving me time finding it

Read more about it here [Helium Superfluid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid_helium-4#Film_flow)

> Superfluid helium-4 is the superfluid form of helium-4, an isotope of the element helium. A superfluid is a state of matter in which the matter behaves like a fluid with zero viscosity. The substance, which looks like a normal liquid, flows without friction past any surface, which allows it to continue to circulate over obstructions and through pores in containers which hold it, subject only to its own inertia.

[image]

> Helium II will "creep" along surfaces in order to find its own level—after a short while, the levels in the two containers will equalize. The Rollin film also covers the interior of the larger container; if it were not sealed, the helium II would creep out and escape.

[image]

> The liquid helium is in the superfluid phase. As long as it remains superfluid, it creeps up the wall of the cup as a thin film. It comes down on the outside, forming a drop which will fall into the liquid below. Another drop will form—and so on—until the cup is empty.

Source from the above link.

This is one of the rare posts that needs a video: [Superfluid Helium](https://youtu.be/2Z6UJbwxBZI)